# Updating Class variable within a instance method

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

```
class MyClass:
    var1 = 1

    def update(value):
        MyClass.var1 += value

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        MyClass.update(value)

a = MyClass(1)
```

I'm trying to update a class variable(**var1**) within a method(**_*init*_**) but I gives me:

```
TypeError: unbound method update() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

I'm doing this because I want easy access to all variables in a class by calling print MyClass.var1

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are confusing *classes* and *instances*.

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

a = MyClass()
```

`MyClass` is a class, `a` is an instance of that class. Your error here is that `update` is an *instance method*. To call it from `__init__`, use either:

```
self.update(value)
```

or

```
MyClass.update(self, value)
```

Alternatively, make `update` a *class method*:

```
@classmethod
def update(cls, value):
    cls.var1 += value
```

Comment: Oh I see, I thought that Class methods were those without the self in it's arguments.

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: className.var1 += 1 is what i was looking for. I was trying to do self.var1 += 1

Answer (score 12):

You need to use the `@classmethod` decorator:

```
$ cat t.py 
class MyClass:
    var1 = 1

    @classmethod
    def update(cls, value):
        cls.var1 += value

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.update(value)

a = MyClass(1)
print MyClass.var1
$ python t.py 
2
```

Comment: You are a life saver! Thanks :)